# Beamer: Problem with table

Tags: beamer

I'm getting trouble trying to make a table in my beamer.
The following is my code:

```
\section{ANÁLISE DE PERFOMANCE DE PORTFÓLIO}
\begin{frame} 
\frametitle{Comportamento dos Mercados}

\hspace{7mm}Quanto maior a volatilidade, maiores ganhos podem ser auferidos agentes especulati-vos, pois, ativos com risco garantem um prêmio.\vspace{0.3cm}

\hspace{7mm}Utilizando a hipótese do random walk e o teste do ADF é possível verificar se um mercado, na hipótese fraca, é eficiente. \vspace{0.3cm}


\begin{tabular}{c | c}
Estatísticas & Valores
\hline \hline
Tau (Observed value) & -2,073
Tau (Critical value) & -0,863
p-value (one-tailed) & 0,563
alpha & 0,05
\end{tabular}


\end{frame}
```

"misplaced \noalign.
\hline ->\noalign 
                  {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule \@height \arrayrulewidth \futurelet...
l.257 \end{frame}"

It's appering this message.
What's wrong with my code?

Comment: The problem are the two `\hline` without a `\\\` ending the line above them.

Answer (score 2):

You did not end the rows of your tabular correctly:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tabular}{c | c}
Estatísticas & Valores\\
\hline \hline
Tau (Observed value) & -2,073\\
Tau (Critical value) & -0,863\\
p-value (one-tailed) & 0,563\\
alpha & 0,05 % no \\ in the last row
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

You have to put `\\` at the end of each line.

This results in:

[image]

You could enhance the table visually. Don't use vertical lines if it's not absolutely necessary. Also you might use the `booktabs` package and use the commands `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule`. Another enhancement could be the `siunitx` package which provides very useful tools for displaying numbers (also in tables).

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tabular}{l S[table-format=-1.3]}
    \toprule
    Estatísticas & {Valores}\\% enclose cells which are not numbers with {...}
    \midrule
    Tau (Observed value) & -2,073\\
    Tau (Critical value) & -0,863\\
    p-value (one-tailed) & 0,563\\
    alpha & 0,05\\ % \\ in the last row because of the \bottomrule
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This results in:

[image]

Comment: Perfetc. It's working now. I would like to centralize the table, is that possible?

Comment: @Arduin Put a `\centering` after `\begin{frame}` to horizontally centre the contents of the frame. To centre the `tabular` environment vertically (if it's the only content of the frame) put a `\vfill` before and one after it.